# Center div inside div (I know, its not working...)

Tags: html, margin, center

Why does this not work? It aligns horizontally correct, but not vertically in Opera. In IE it dosent work at all.

http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/340/86238198.png

```
#footer
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 905px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 800px;
    height: 95px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-image: url('footerbg.png');
}

#center
{
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    height: 70%;
    margin: auto;

    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: are you using a doctype?

Comment: Holy crap. I changed from HTML 4.01 Transitional to strict and it works now...Any explanation why this made it work?

Answer (score 1):

In Transitional (quirks mode), IE maintains the behavior of its older browsers, so as to not break pre-existing websites that were constructed to look ok in IE 5.  So in IE 6 and up, if you do not define a Strict doctype, then it will resort to its old incorrect behavior of not honoring margin:auto.